# What do with this issue, when i start my server on Django?

Tags: python, django

When I start my server on Djano i have such issue.

```
(myvenv) orlov@orlov-System-Product-Name:~/Desktop/back_v0.1$ python manage.py runserver

Error processing line 1 of /home/orlov/Desktop/back_v0.1/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dj-0.1-nspkg.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 174, in addpackage
      exec(line)
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 568, in module_from_spec
  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'
```

What is it?

Comment: did you update django after create the project?

Comment: Yes, i updated all packages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted file - dj-0.1-nspkg.pth and this issue has gone